# Odoo: How to override row click of a tree view to open a different model form

Tags: odoo

In Odoo 12 i'm constructing my own reports, and since they are not based on a single model, I had to rely on SQL views to execute a SQL query so i can get the result that i want, the thing is, this view is presented on a tree view just fine but when i click on any row it doesn't know what to open (since it's not based on an actual model), what i wanna do is, override the row click function to open a certain model that i want but i can't find anything on the internet that leads to such action

Comment: If you used a tree view with a model created using an SQL query, the corresponding record should be opened in a form view when you click on a row. Please provide more details?

Comment: actually it doesn't, let me put down the sql query, it selects fields from different tables, so it doesn't correspond to an actual model, hence when you click on it , nothing happens
actually it doesn't, let me put down the sql query, it selects fields from different tables, so it doesn't correspond to an actual model, hence when you click on it , nothing happens
https://pastebin.com/yy25jg77

Comment: I tested it on [account_invoice_report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/report/account_invoice_report.py#L7). Please add a screenshot of the tree view

Comment: it's a custom module, i don't think it would work on the native modules but here's a gif of it https://imgur.com/lHI3Ia9

Comment: Did you use a custom tree view?

Comment: yes it's not a native module or model, it's all a custom module that i've made,  but built on the same principles of odoo
https://pastebin.com/bi6yhxwk

Comment: I mean, do you have altered the tree view and changed the js code?

Comment: no i didn't at all, that's what i'm asking if there's a way whether in python or jquery to override the row click

Comment: The row click will be disabled because the `view_mode` is set only to `tree` mode. The tree view in the example seems to be personalized and it is possible to get the same result by altering the [_onRowClicked](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L773) function of the tree view renderer.

Comment: thank you @Kenly, but is there any fucntion in odoo to do so? since i'm not that aware of jquery programming

Comment: It is handled by the web client and you should have knowledge of Javascript basics and jQuery to customize it.

Comment: You are welcome